# C function to capitalize first word in a sentence, handles arbitrary spaces

Tags: c, strings

The code below capitalized the first letter of every word in a sentence. It handles an arbitrary number of spaces in any part of string. It works. Can it be optimized further?

```
void capitalize_string(char *s) {
  while(*s) {
    while (*s && *s == ' ')
      s++;
    *s = toupper(*s);
    s++;
    while (*s && *s != ' ')
      s++;
  }
}
```

Comment: In `*s && *s == ' '` the left condition is excessive since it is always true whenever the right one holds. After the first non-space lookup is done you should check that you haven't found the string's end, otherwise with a string ending in spaces your program crashes.

Answer (score 7):

## Declare the `toupper` function

The easiest way to provide a prototype is

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

## Consider matching all whitespace

At present, we don't capitalize a word at the beginning of a line.  We could deal with this by using `isspace()` instead of testing for equality with `' '`.  Also, we might want to consider a word to start when a letter immediately follows punctuation (such as `"`, `/` or `-`).

## Bug: if the string ends with a space

Consider the string `"  "` and walk through.

We loop while `(*s && *s == ' ')` until `s` points at the terminating NUL character.  Now we upcase that NUL (which is harmless), and increment `s` again.  That's not good.

We need

```
 if (!*s) { break; }
```

before line 6.

## An alternative approach

Instead of changing between two different loops for whitespace and non-whitespace runs, we can write a single loop if we use a variable to remember what we've most recently seen; I'll call it `prev`.  Start off with it set to a space, so that we'll capitalise the first letter of the string.  The code then looks like this:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void capitalize_string(char *s)
{
    for (int prev = ' ';  *s;  ++s) {
        int current = (unsigned char)*s;
        if (!isalnum(prev) && isalpha(current)) {
            *s = (char)toupper(current);
        }
        prev = current;
    }
}
```

Note that the `<ctype.h>` functions all accept (and return) an `int` that represents an `unsigned char` version of a character - on platforms where plain `char` is signed, passing one directly can be undefined behaviour.

Here's a short test program so we can give command-line arguments to try out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 1;  i < argc;  ++i) {
        capitalize_string(argv[i]);
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

A more sophisticated test allows us to check a suite of examples every time we make a change to the code, and allows us to be explicit about our expectations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int check(const char *input, const char *expected)
{
    char *s = malloc(strlen(input)+1);
    if (!s) {
        perror("malloc");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(s, input);

    int err_count = 0;
    capitalize_string(s);
    if (strcmp(s, expected)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "*** Input \"%s\"; expected \"%s\"; got \"%s\"\n",
                input, expected, s);
        ++err_count;
    }

    free(s);
    return err_count;
}

int main()
{
    return check("", "")
        +  check("123", "123")
        +  check("ab", "Ab")
        +  check("AB", "AB")
        +  check("ab cd", "Ab Cd")
        +  /* add more tests here */
        +  check("harley-davidson", "Harley-Davidson")
        ;
}
```

Comment: Some good stuff here, but the question is "Can it be optimized further?"  Checking the character class of each character twice is likely to be less optimal.  Of course, correct, understandable, and simple are all at least as important as fast.

Comment: @Adrian - since the kind of optimization wasn't mentioned, I fell back to my default: optimize for _maintainability_.  Well, that's my excuse for not addressing performance, and I'll stick to it!

Answer (score 3):

```
void capitalize_string(char *s) {
  char prev_char = ' ';

  while(*s) {
    if (isspace((unsigned char)prev_char) && islower((unsigned char)*s)) {
      *s = (char)toupper((unsigned char)*s);
    }
    prev_char = *s;
    s++;
  }
}
```

Improvements -

- Testing characters using ctype.h functions is the safest way to ensure that such programs work irrespective of [locale](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locales.html#Locales).
- The [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of the original function was higher than it needed to be; the inner while loops weren't necessary.
- The original function had many bugs. After the first inner while loop you should have checked if the character wasn't a '\0' (to `break`), and if it were a lowercase alphabet, before applying the toupper().

Comment: `isspace(c)` and `islower(c)` are UB when `c < 0`.  Suggest `islower((unsigned char) c)`

Comment: Nice tight alternative code.

Comment: @chux - How does that typecast help when the char value is (say) -1? Wouldn't it be better to add an assert to verify that the value of the char is not less than 0?

Comment: When a `char` is _signed_ and has a  value in the range `[CHAR_MIN...-1]`, it certainly originated as an `unsigned char` from some function like `fgetc()`, etc.  Casting it back to `unsigned char` is sensible.  The `assert()` is an OK alternative.  It really all depends on coding goals for values outside `[0...CHAR_MAX]`.  The cast is a minimal defined solution.

Comment: The cast is to avoid UB: With `<ctype.h>`, "In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined." C11 7.4 1

Answer (score 2):

Make the problem statement more specific and explicit.  Since the question title doesn't match description in the post, I'm wondering if you've got a clear enough idea of what you want.

Do you care about ASCII or some other subset of Unicode?  Which encoding(s) do you want to support?  Do you want the same behavior regardless of locale?

What about punctuation that separates words?  (e.g., should the `h` in `i said, "hello."` be capitalized because it's the first letter of a word even though it's not preceded by a space?)

Create a set of test cases so you can quickly check if a change you make causes a regression.

```
int main() {
    assert(strcmp("", capitalize("")) == 0);
    assert(strcmp("Abc", capitalize("abc")) == 0);
    assert(strcmp("Hello World", capitalize("hello world")) == 0);
    assert(strcmp("  Go  For  It  ", capitalize("  go  for  it  ")) == 0);
    assert(strcmp("(Be Mine)", capitalize("(be mine)")) == 0);
    // etc.
    return 0;
}
```

Now you can experiment to find the clearest, fastest way to implement what you want.

Comment: Yes, it's a great idea to have a test suite.  My preference is slightly more work - a test function that allows `main()` to keep going after a failure, and shows all the failing tests - that way, I can quickly undo a change that causes 50% of them to fail.  That looks like `int main() { return check("", "") + check("abc", "Abc") + ... ; }`.

Comment: There is a problem here - `capitalize()` requires a *modifiable* string, so you can't pass a string literal like that.

Comment: @Toby Speight:  That gets to my point about making the problem statement more explicit.  If you want to handle something more than ASCII or other simple character set, you can't always do it in place.  Capitalizing a ligature or an accented character can mean that you no longer have a 1:1 ratio between the number of before and after chars.

Comment: Yes, I should have realised the implied change to the function prototype (particularly as you obviously have a different return type!).

Answer (score 1):

Two things came to my mind:

1. The task of finding the first non-whitespace character could be solved using `strspn`, which is not only shorter but might also be useful in case you decide to consider e.g. tab characters as whitespace, too.
2. Depending on your compiler optimisations (in particular, whether your compiler can optimise tail-recursive functions), you could consider a recursive definition which finds the first non-whitespace, (tries to) upper case it and then processes the remainder of the string.

```
void capitalize_string(char *s) {
    if (!*s)
        return;
    s += strspn(s, " ");
    *s = toupper(*s);
    capitalize_string(++s);
}
```